# Update text of title in a listview

Tags: flutter

I have a listview with ListTiles in it and I want to change title text on onTap method.
Here's what I've tried:

```
body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {          

          //My thought was to use a variable to hold a reference to the Text widget
          var title = Text(
            'Old text',
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            maxLines: 1,
          );

          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.android),
            title: title,
            onTap: () => setState(
              () => {
                title = Text(//here I assign a new reference with the new value
                  'New text',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
              },
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              'Subtitle text',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
            trailing: Icon(
              Icons.android,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

I tried to search a solution but unsuccessful...

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: The code looks like you want to change the title, not the subtitle. Which one do you actually want to change?

Comment: @kaboc oops! Updated the question, my bad... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `setState()` in a widget which has lots of descendants, it causes rebuilds of all of them and can affect the performance of the app. It is better to use it only in leaf widgets of the tree. A better approach is to separate the child into a StatefulWidget class as below.

Or, it'll be good to use other approaches like [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) or the BLoC pattern.

Here is an example using setState().

```dart
body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _MyListTile(
      title: 'Old text',
      subTitle: 'Subtitle text',
    );
  },
),
```

```dart
class _MyListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const _MyListTile({this.title, this.subTitle});

  final String title;
  final String subTitle;

  @override
  _MyListTileState createState() => _MyListTileState();
}

class _MyListTileState extends State<_MyListTile> {
  String _title;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _title = widget.title;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.android),
      title: Text(_title),
      onTap: () => setState(
        () => _title = 'New text',
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        widget.subTitle,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        maxLines: 1,
      ),
      trailing: Icon(
        Icons.android,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using list to display data, your title and subtitle should come from there. You can have a list of map or something similar like this:

```
List<Map> list = [
    {
      "name": "Android",
      "version": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "iOS",
      "version": 12
    }
];
```

In title, you can use:

```
title: Text(list[index]["name"]),
```

You can create a function to change the title text on tap.

```
void changeTitle(int index) {
    setState((){
      list[index]["name"] = "New Text";
    });
}
```

In the above function you can use `setState` instead of directly in the list view.

In the `onTap` of ListView, you can simply call the function with index.

```
onTap: () => changeTitle(index),
```

Tapping on which the changes will reflect in the subtitle.