# How to avoid rebuild of UI when setstate of checkbox?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am new to flutter app development. I am trying to implement a simple signin screen with 2 text box and a remember me check box. My code was working file adding a builder inside body. When I type the username and password and click the checkbox, whatever I typed is cleared. I am able to see that the ui itself pained again but don’t know how to overcome this. Below is my code,

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn>
{

  bool _obscureText = true; // Variable to toggle between Show and Hide Password
  bool _checkedStatus = false; // Variable to toggle checked status
  /*
   * Function to show or hide password text
   */
  void _toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }
  void _rememberMe()
  {
    setState(() {
      _checkedStatus = !_checkedStatus;
    });
  }
  /*
   * Function to validate username and password
   */
  String _validate(String username,String password)
  {


      if(username.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty)
      {
        return "valid";

      }
      else if(username.isEmpty && password.isEmpty)
      {

        return "Please enter valid Userid and password";

      }
      else if(username.isEmpty && password.isNotEmpty)
      {
        return "Please enter your Userid";
      }
      else if(password.isEmpty && username.isNotEmpty)
      {
        return "Please enter your password";
      }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    final _useridController = TextEditingController();
    final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
    void _signin(BuildContext context){
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
              builder:(context)=>newList()
              ));
}
return Scaffold(

      body: Builder(
              builder:(context)=> SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) * 0.4,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/images/app_logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, bottom: 0),
                  ),//Logo Part
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20, right: 20),
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top) * 0.6,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('User Id',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'MX',
                        fontSize: 12
                        ), 
                        ),

                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                      TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          hintText: 'Enter your User Id',
                          contentPadding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 2, 2),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                            ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                            ),
                          ),
                          controller: _useridController,
                        ),//User Id TextBox
                        SizedBox(height: 25,),
                        Text('Password',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12
                        ), ),

                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Password',
                        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 2, 2),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)
                        ),
                        suffixIcon: _obscureText ? IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.visibility), onPressed: _toggle) : IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.visibility_off), onPressed: _toggle,)                   
                        ),
                        controller: _passwordController,
                        obscureText: _obscureText,
                        ),//Password TextField


                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            onPressed: (){},
                            child:Text('Forget Password',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                          style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12
                          ), ),
                        )),//Forget Password Button
                         Container( 
                           child: Row(
                             children: <Widget>[
                               Checkbox( 
                                  value: _checkedStatus,
                                  onChanged:(val){
                                    _rememberMe();
                                  } ,
                                  activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,

                               ),
                               Text('Remember Me'),
                             ],
                           ),
                         ),//Remember Me
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 45,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              onPressed:()=> _signin(context),
                              child: Text(

                                'Sign In',

                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.white)
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),//SignIn Button


                  ],),
                )
              ],),
          ),
        ),
      )

    );
  }
  void _showToast(BuildContext context,String msg) {
    final scaffold = Scaffold.of(context);
    scaffold.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content:  Text(msg)
        )
    );
  }
```

Can someone help me with this. Please tell me if I am developing this concept in wrong way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put everything in a single StatefulWidget/State as in your code, some change in only part of the widget causes the rebuild of the whole widget. Extract the checkbox as a separate widget to avoid it.

Comment: Any sample code to do that? @kaboc

Comment: Here's my answer to another question similar to yours. It's a case with ListTile instead of Checkbox, but the approach there can be applied to your case too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60814759/12086560

Comment: @kaboc I would try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the two TextEditingControllers in the build method:

```dart
final _useridController = TextEditingController();
final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

They hold the state, aka what the current content of the text fields is. Because you are swapping out the old controllers with new ones on every call of the build method, the text fields are cleared whenever the checkbox requests a rebuild.

You should not create controllers in the build method. Instead, create member variables in the `_SignInState` class, and construct the controllers within the `initState` method (overriding from the `State` class). Additionally, you should call each controller's `dispose` methods within `_SignInState`'s `dispose`.

So in your `_SignInState` class, add:

```dart
TextEditingController _useridController;
TextEditingController _passwordController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _useridController = TextEditingController();
  _passwordController = TextEditingController();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _useridController.dispose();
  _passwordController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

and then remove the two lines

```dart
final _useridController = TextEditingController();
final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

from the build method.